# Plot two lines on the same row on a graph

Tags: graph, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs, medical

I am trying to create a medical graph to display the heart rate. It will have the live data on the left part and the prediction forecast on the right. I will get both from the backend API, and I need now to show them as one line on the graph. I am using ReactJs and chart.JS.
Look the picture below to understand better:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWd6H.jpg)tter:

I just tried to do the regression but it will be done from the backend. I am getting from the API two fields: live data: and prediction:
And I need them to add them together.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `segment` option for this. You can change line styles based on datapoint options / value.
Usage example: [Link an official example](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/line/segments.html)